# What is the best approach: Labeled training data and unlabeled test data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, semi-supervised-learning

I'm new into the data science world and I am working on improving my knowledge so here is my problem:

I want to build a binary classifier with the following constraints:

I have 2 files training.csv and test.csv The first file contains a dataset with 59 numerical features and a label that should be predicted. The second file contains a dataset with the same features but without a label.

My question is:

How to predict the unknown labels with a suitable evaluation method?

```
EDIT
```

-I want to achieve binary classification on unlabeled test data while training it on labeled data.

Data:

-train data: 795 rows with 59 numerical features and a label (blanaced 0:495, 1:300).

-test data: 91 rows with 59 numerical features but without a label

my question is: How to approach this kind of problems with suitable evaluation metrics.

Comment: You did not give any details about your problem and data except stating that it's an ML problem.

Comment: If you need any further details please let me know maybe I can provide you with what I understood from the task because that's literally  what I got for now. @gunes

Comment: I am not looking for a code or a complete solution I just want to understand how to tackle this kind of problems @gunes

Comment: There are a myriad ways to address binary classification problems (e.g. logistic regression). You should give more information about what you want to achieve, the nature of the problem, and your data. It's for you to get better answers here, not that I want you to do.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @gunes I edited my question, I hope it's clearer now

Comment: Seems like this is a standard binary classification problem, there are many possible methods to tackle it. You can look at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_classification) to get some ideas.

Comment: You need to give us more details, otherwise, the answer is “use machine learning”. It is not clear what is your specific problem in here.

Comment: What are the details that should be added I would be happy if you explained more @Tim

Comment: Any details that would clarify why the obvious “use machine learning” doesn't already answer your question.

Comment: the test data are unlabeled so how can I measure the classifier performance? @Tim

Comment: You can't, at least not using the test data you have.

Comment: @Tim Thank you for your help!